# what does max() function do in javascript if array has several equally large numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, max

If we get something like

```
array=[5,5,5,5,3,2];
return Math.max.Apply(Math,array);
```

How do I get it to return the numbers from first to last if such a case occurs.

Comment: The `Math.max()` function returns **one** number. You'd have to write your own function if you want to return a list of the numbers equal to the largest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in the title:

> what does max() function do in javascript if array has several equally
>   large numbers

The answer is, nothing. Math.max() doesn't act on arrays.

You can pass an array by spreading the items as arguments to `max()`:

```
Math.max(...[1,2,3]) // 3
```

Or as you've seen, with `apply()`:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, [1,2,3]) // 3
```

If the question is more:

> What does Math.max() do when more than one of the same maximum number is given?

The answer is, it returns that number:

```
const a = [5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2]
const max = Math.max(...a)

console.log(max) // 5
```

This question is confusing:

> How do I get it to return the numbers from first to last if such a case occurs.

You want it to return a sorted array? From `[5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2]` to `[2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5]`?

```
a.sort() // [2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

You want dupes removed? From `[5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2]` to `[2, 3, 5]`?

```
Array.from(new Set(a)) // [2, 3, 5]
```

Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is the following:

```
var a = [5,5,5,5,3,2];
var largest = Math.max.apply(null,a)
var filtered = a.filter(function(item) {
    item === largest
});
```

Where filtered will have contain all the largest elements.

In @Clarkie's example, he's calling Math.max more frequently than needed.
In both Dan and Clarkie's example they're capitalizing Apply which is incorrect, the correct function to call is `Math.max.apply`  and Math need not be passed in as the first argument.

See the following for a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/fx5ut2mm/

Answer (score -1):

Modifying @Clarkie's very nice idea. We can boil it down to...

```js
var a = [5,5,5,5,3,2],
    m = Math.max(...a),
    f = a.filter(e => e == m);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(f) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: There's absolutely no indication that @Ignacio Bricchi is looking for a solution using ES2015, nor that he wants to write the result to a document.  This answer makes assumptions that complicate the solution therefore taking away from the simple problem he is attempting to solve.

Comment: @sheeldotme You must be terribly confused. Your code involves arrow functions and const declaration.

Comment: I must have been, you're definitely right!  Great catch, I've now changed the code to be what it should have been in the first place, thanks @Redu